# Como abrir uma página externa no phonegap ao clicar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache-cordova

hoje comecei a desenvolver utilizando PhoneGap, porém me deparei com um problema, que é clicar em um link e não conseguir abrir uma página externa, como se fosse uma nova activity, como eu posso realizar esse procedimento só usando html,css e javascript ? Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Você deseja abrir a página fora do PhoneGap?

Comment: Desejo abrir uma outra tela no próprio PhoneGap, como se fosse no WebView do android que você pode configurar para que ao ir pra outra página, ele abra na própria aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é aconselhável abrir páginas externas dentro da própria aplicação Cordova. Se você precisa apenas abrir páginas externas, basta chamar o browser padrão do dispositivo por:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl("seuLink", { openExternal:true } );
```

Em último caso, se você precisar mesmo abrir uma página interna em seu App Cordova/PhoneGap, tente com iframe. No entanto, como dito, isso pode causar muito problemas na maneira como o App funciona (eventos de `Backbutton`, por exemplo, podem não funcionar mais como o esperado).

**PS:** Além disso, a partir do Cordova 4.0, foi implementado o plugin padrão de *WhiteList*. Talvez seja necessário configurar as páginas que você abrirá antecipadamente.

Espero que ajude. :)